# How to execute a command under Linux after booting without a TTY session?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, tty, init

I'm creating a kiosk PC at the moment and I'm wondering if this is possible:

When the PC is started and Linux Debian boots and I wonder if it's possible to start the command `startx` respectively `xinit /home/kiosk/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 -auth /tmp/serverauth.2FksDI7OqU` without starting a TTY session.

Background is, I don't want people to be able to get a shell via CTRL + ALT + F1-F6.

I know I could disable them via `/etc/inittab` but then I can't start my X session.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are kiosk-style distributions (or configurations) around, perhaps the quite old) http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Kiosk-HOWTO.html is of help. Or search for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify your ServerFlags section in xorg.conf without the need to fiddle with inittab:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a system which runs inittab anymore, but I believe it would simply be a matter of removing the shells for the runlevel which runs X (ie remove 5 from the entries in inittab)

This could work because in order to boot X, many systems switch the runlevel to 5.  Of-course, it does assume your system handles runlevels a particular way.  (And, indeed, another part of the solution may be to tell init to launch to runlevel 5 rather then an runlevel 2/3 depending on the distro )